# What's the equivalent of type-specific extension methods in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype, extension-methods, type-safety

Say you have a class `Person`. Its definition is the following:

```
function Person(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}
```

Now say you have an array of `Persons` (or people) and you want to find the oldest one. In C#, you would do this via extension methods:

```
Person Oldest(this IEnumerable<Person> people) =>
    people.OrderByDescending(p => p.Age).First();

// Usage:
var elder = people.Oldest();
```

What's the equivalent in JavaScript? So far, this is all I was able to come up with:

```
Array.prototype.oldest = function() {
    return this.slice().sort(function(left, right) {
        return left.age - right.age;
    }).pop();
};
```

This works well and has the same syntax as C#, but has a few drawbacks:

1) It modifies the prototype of a builtin, which could potentially lead to conflicts with other libraries that do so.

2) It is not type-safe: it's easy to accidentally call on an array that doesn't contain people, which could lead to a runtime error.

Alternatively, you could define it like this:

```
function oldest(people) {
    // ...
}
```

But then you would have to call it like `oldest(people)` instead of `people.oldest()`, which would hamper readability.

Is there any type-safe, syntactically "nice" way to do this in JavaScript that I'm missing?

Comment: I'd just use `oldest(people)` and return the oldest Person, easy and safe, and in my opinion much more readable than assigning new properties to built-ins

Comment: for the oldest, it does not require to sort, just iterate over and return the set with the greatest value.

Comment: Sorting is `n log n`. An argmax can be done linearly. Just iterate from the beginning to the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because js isn't type safe, you're better off implementing that method as `oldest(people)` ...

Just think of it as a decorator pattern - a legit approach to projecting functionality into an unknown set of related entities.

Then - you can do type-checking within your function.

You could **namespace** it to make the syntax more "obvious" if that's your concern I guess:

```
personList(persons).getOldest()
```

As one objective-c-ish example.

Then, you can add your type-specific checking to the creator for personList:

```
function personList(persons) {

     //iterate over persons and make sure 
     //it's valid. return undefined or {} if not. 

     return {
         getOldest: function() {
              // insert clever code here ...
              persons.slice().dice().puree();
          },
          getYoungest: function() {
             //even more clever code here ...
          }
      }

}
```

With that approach, the code

```
PersonList(cats).getOldest()
```

With throw a 'getOldest undefined' error -- which makes it easy to spot the problem when you have 11,000,000 lines of js code to sort through.

It has the added advantage of making your c# inner-child feel more at home (with a js file called "ArrayExtensions.Persons.js" in your project folder). Feels like "chicken soup for the c# soul," right?

Answer (score 1):

You can try different approaches:

- If you only have one array of `Person`s in your program, you can add the method as an own property of the array.

  ```
  var people = [person1, person2];
  people.oldest = function() {
    // Find the oldest person in this array
  };
  // ... later
  people.oldest();
  ```
- You can define your method as an static property of `Person`, and pass the array of `Person`s as an argument:

  ```
  Person.oldest = function(people) {
     // Find the oldest person in an array
  };
  var people = [person1, person2];
  Person.oldest(people);
  ```
- Extend `Array` (requires ES6)

  ```
  class People extends Array {
    oldest() {
      // Find the oldest person in a People collection
    }
  }
  var people = new People();
  people.push(person1, person2);
  people.oldest();
  ```

Comment: Hm, I like the `Person.oldest()` idea. Makes things more organized.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach with a prototype of sorting. `Person.prototype.ageCompare` checks if the parameter is instance of `Person` and throws an error if not.

```js
function Person(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

Person.prototype.ageCompare = function (b) {
    if (!(b instanceof Person)) {
        throw 'b is no instance of Person!';
    }
    return this.age - b.age;
};


var peoples = [new Person('Tim', 31), new Person('Jane', 32), new Person('Frank', 28), new Person('Sue', 31), new Person('Baby', 2)];
peoples.sort(function (a, b) { return a.ageCompare(b); });
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(peoples, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```